# Reference : Special case of Banach-valued function integration by parts

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, integration

Let $u \in L^p (0,T; L^1(\Omega))$ with $\partial_t u \in L^p(0,T; L^1(\Omega))$ and $v \in L^q (0,T; L^\infty(\Omega))$ with $\partial_t u \in L^q(0,T; L^\infty(\Omega))$ (with $1/p+1/q=1$ and $p \in (1,\infty)$). $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary.

Is it true that
$$
\int_0^T \int_\Omega \partial_t u v + \int_0^T \int_\Omega u \partial_t v = \int_\Omega u(t=T)v(t=T) - \int_\Omega u(t=0)v(t=0)
$$
and where can I find a reference for such a result.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $\partial_t u$ here?

Comment: @NateEldredge $\partial_t u$ is the derivative (in the sense of the distribution) of the function $u : (0,T)\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. $u$ is considered as a function of $n+1$ variables (time + space). What definition do you have in mind ?

Comment: I would start looking in Zeidler's books on functional analysis but I don't have access right now.

Comment: @Dirk Zeidler wrote at least 5 books on functional analysis. Can you specify which one you have in mind?

Comment: @NateEldredge The derivative can also be viewed as the distributional derivative (for $L^1(\Omega)$-valued functions).